# How to get percentage axes in a Highcharts Treemap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a HighCharts Treemap showing a set of categories containing subcategories. The point of the graph is to show how much of the data is in Category A, and how much of Category A is in Subcategory A1.

I have created this as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/jbcfk93m/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
        colorByPoint: true,
        layoutAlgorithm: "stripes",
        alternateStartingDirection: true,
        allowPointSelect: true,
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                        alert(this.name + ": " + this.value);
                    }
                }
        },
        dataLabels: {

        },
        type: "treemap",
        levels: [{
            level: 1,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'right',
                rotation: 30,
                crop: false,
                overflow: 'none',
                inside: false,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '15px',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }
        }, {
            level: 2,
            dataLabels: {
                style: {
                }
            },
            layoutAlgorithm: "stripes",
        }],
        data: [{
            // Add parents without values
            id: 'CategoryA',
            name: 'Category A'
        }, {
            id: 'CategoryB',
            name: 'Category B',
        }, {
            // And the children with values
            name: 'Subcat A1',
            value: 4,
            parent: 'CategoryA'
        }, {
            name: 'Subcat A2',
            value: 6,
            parent: 'CategoryA'
        }, {
            name: 'Subcat B1',
            value: 6,
            parent: 'CategoryB'
        }, {
            name: 'Subcat B2',
            value: 2,
            parent: 'CategoryB'
        }
        ]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Treemap',
        margin: 100
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    }
});
});
```

I want to get both the X- and Y axes in the graph to show percentages so I can more easily see how much of my data is in a certain category.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't find anything about axis on treemaps and i'm not really sure if showing a percentage on X and Y axis would help you that much, because you basically have to multiply the values on X and Y(eg. if your subcat B1 is from 20% to 100% on X axis and from 60% to 100% on the Y axis then you would have to do (100% - 20%) * (100% - 60%) = 32%).

I did implement however a tooltip formatter that will show you the percentage when you hover over the subcategories.

```
formatter: function () {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.series.data.length; i++)
    {
        if (this.series.data[i].node.children.length == 0)
        total+=this.series.data[i].node.val;
    }
    var value;
    if (this.point.node.children.length == 0)
    {
        value = this.point.options.value;
    }
    else
    {
        value = this.point.node.childrenTotal;
    }

    return this.key + " " + (value / total) *100 + " %";
}
```

Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jbcfk93m/4/